# How to open sqlite3 database using PDO not in same directory?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

How i can open a database using this line:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sqlite');
```

if my db not in this directory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the same scheme, but put the full path.

```
sqlite:/path/to/db.sqlite
```